# Is there any file I can read in unix which contains the time

Tags: unix, php

Is there any file in unix based system which I can read, to get the same value that time() in php would return?

Comment: Will you be reading the file using php?

Comment: If you can execute commands, use `date +%s`.

Comment: I can only use a read_file function to do this so a command wouldn't work.

Comment: Apparently PHP has a `time()` function.  Why do you need to read it from a file?

Comment: What is the *actual* end problem that you're trying to solve? (this smells like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike my other answer reading metadata, grepping through /proc for "sec" I indeed found a file containing the current system time:

`/proc/timer_list` contains two values: the uptime in nsec (now at...) and a little further down the time the system was started, also in nsec (.offset). If you add them and divide through 10^9 you've got the current time.

```
Timer List Version: v0.6
HRTIMER_MAX_CLOCK_BASES: 2
now at 2089173850911347 nsecs

cpu: 0
 clock 0:
  .base:       0000000000000000
  .index:      0
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .get_time:   ktime_get_real
  .offset:     1316955129915578545 nsecs
```

EDIT: And another one: `/sys/devices/pnp0/00:05/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch` seems to contain the real unix timestamp, no offset or such. But I'm not sure about what this file is really about, just found it grepping.

If you've also got some terminal access for development you can try yourself:

```
grep 131904 `find /sys 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null
```

to find files containing the first digits of the unix timestamp (replace if using it later) in /sys you've got access to.

Comment: But you still need to tell us what you want to do exactly. Sorry for being curios. ;)

Comment: This will be really offtopic but I will, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEmO7wQKCMw at Defcon shows how a PHPSESSID cookie can be bruteforced by knowing some of its varables which include the epoch time of php. I've been trying to think of a way of getting that, and I was looking for a file to read with load_file (mysql injection), that will give me this value. There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's time() function returns seconds since the Unix epoch. You can format it as a date and/or time any way you want using other PHP functions.

Unix's date command (at least the GNU version) can do the same

```
# date "+%s"
1319042692
```

So you can easily create a file containing that number, as needed (e.g. using PHP's system() function)

Or just read it directly

```
$secs_since_epoch = system('date "+%s"', $return_value);
```

I can't think of a sensible use case for what you ask though.

Answer (score 0):

- On my system, `/proc/cpuinfo`'s {a|c|m}time is equal to the current system time.
- Maybe you can just execute `date` and read from its output?

Comment: I have tried doing cat /proc/cpuinfo but can't find the time anywhere, just cpu specifications, why?

Comment: As i stated you need to read its meta data (eg. `stat cpuinfo`). The time is not in the file, but the file's metadata equals it.

Comment: Oh ok, but unfortunately I can only use read_file(path) for this, and it won't do the trick